# CentOS 7 screen session has been terminated unexpectedly

Tags: centos7, gnu-screen, unexpected-shutdown

I've default CentOS7 server without any additional software except of WildFly10 and I'm the only user there.

I'd run WildFly using `screen` command and logged out from the server until it became unavailable after ~20 days of successful online.

Logs of WildFly show nothing weird but `ps aux` shows there's no `screen` process anymore and `/var/log/messages` has few unclear lines for me:

```
Jan 22 13:06:01 p000000 systemd: Starting Session c386 of user root.
Jan 22 13:06:01 p000000 systemd: Started Session c386 of user root.
Jan 22 13:09:01 p000000 systemd: Starting Unmount All Filesystems.
Jan 22 13:09:01 p000000 systemd: Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
Jan 22 13:09:01 p000000 systemd: Stopping Session c137 of user root.
Jan 22 13:09:01 p000000 systemd: Stopped Session c137 of user root.
Jan 22 13:09:01 p000000 systemd: Stopping user-0.slice.
Jan 22 13:09:01 p000000 systemd: Removed slice user-0.slice.
Jan 22 13:09:01 p000000 systemd: Stopping Dump dmesg to /var/log/dmesg...
Jan 22 13:09:01 p000000 systemd: Stopped Dump dmesg to /var/log/dmesg.
Jan 22 13:09:01 p000000 systemd: Stopping Graphical Interface.
Jan 22 13:09:01 p000000 systemd: Stopped target Graphical Interface.
Jan 22 13:09:01 p000000 systemd: Stopping Multi-User System.
Jan 22 13:09:01 p000000 systemd: Stopped target Multi-User System.
Jan 22 13:09:01 p000000 systemd: Stopping OpenSSH server daemon...
Jan 22 13:09:01 p000000 systemd: Stopping SASL authentication daemon....
Jan 22 13:09:01 p000000 systemd: Stopping Xinetd A Powerful Replacement For Inetd...
Jan 22 13:09:01 p000000 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.7" x-pid="107" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
Jan 22 13:09:19 p000000 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.7" x-pid="106" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
```

What there's happened? Why did `screen` process went unexpected down?

Comment: It appears the server was rebooted. Processes tend not to survive that.

Comment: Don't run services in `screen`. This is not professional and has many problems, such as the one you ran into. Set up a proper systemd service for it instead.